# Unable to compile apache server httpd 2.4.57 for windows

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-proxy, forward-proxy

I have just started to work with Apache server Httpd.

I want to compile source code for windows

Can anyone please help me for this ?

I have tried following ways to build

1. compile using visual studio 2017
   followed below article but getting many build error related to wrong syntax (in actual that is correct syntax)

[https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/win_compiling.html#page-header:~:text=Comments-,Building%20httpd%20with%20the%20included%20Visual%20Studio%20project%20files,-Requirements](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/win_compiling.html#page-header:%7E:text=Comments-,Building%20httpd%20with%20the%20included%20Visual%20Studio%20project%20files,-Requirements)

Note : Migration done successfully from unix to windows while open Apache.dsw file first time.

2. compile using cmake

Added missing libraries even it's showing missing errors.

```
 See also "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/httpd-2.4.57/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\httpd-2.4.57>cmake -G “Visual Studio 15 2017"
-A x64
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25027.0
- Check for working C compiler: c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25 1017/bin/HostX86/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25 1017/bin/HostX86/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_LIBRARIES LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find LuaS1 (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:106 (MESSAGE): APR include directory C:/Program Files (x86)/HTTPD/include is not correct.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/httpd-2.4.57/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\httpd-2.4.57>
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain _all_ the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and provide a [mcve] _in this question_ (instead of stating that you follow some external tutorial, give us the actual steps that you followed, _right here_: We don't want to read through a lengthy article before having an idea what you did, and the question should be self-containing, to be a reference for others who might have similar problems when a linked tutorial has changed)